Is it possible to typesafe strapi lifecycle hooks?
I'm trying to add types to strapi lifecycles, so far I've found nothing useful on the docs or a google search.
// foo/lifecycle.js

export default {
  afterCreate: (event: any) => {
    // event.result to be typed
  },
};

Is it possible to get the event type from some hidden place in @strapi/strapi ?
I'm using v4 by the way

I managed to type lifecycle events like so:
import { Attribute } from '@strapy/types';
import { Event } from '@strapi/database/dist/lifecycles';

type LifecycleEvent<T> = Event & {
  result?: T; // since result is only available in `afterXXX` events
}
type MyEvent = LifecycleEvent<Attribute.GetValues<'api::admin.admin'>>;

export default {
  beforeCreate: async (event: MyEvent) => {
    await validateData(event);
  },
  beforeUpdate: async (event: MyEvent) => {
    event.state.updatedFields = await getUpdatedFields(event);
  },
  afterUpdate: async (event: MyEvent) => {
    await syncData(event);
  },
};


Thanks for sharing this. Even though many Strapi projects exist, most still use JS.  It's always great to see an example of Strapi with TypeScript.  If you have any additional cool examples or lessons learned using Strapi with Typescript, we do have a WFC program where you can share your experience.
